# How to see the scope content in the console in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I’m working on an angularJs project, I need to debug a variable in the $scope, but for some weird reason I’m not able to set breakpoints in my browser developer console, I’m using IE9
Is there any way to see the contain of a var within the scope, without set breakpoints?

Comment: one of the way is using `console.log()` but you should open you console before running page..because `window.console` object is not available in IE9

Comment: a tip for developing with angular - Batarang: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways of doing that is:

Write in the console:
angular.element($('#elementId')).scope() //you’ll see the contain of the $scope
You have to make sure that the element you select is within the html element that define the controller, E.g:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
          <div  id="elementId'">This div is within MyCtrl controller</div>
     </div>
```

Other way to achieve it is:
Binding a variable using the json filter, so you can see the content of a variable printed as json in your view

```
    <div>{{myVar | json}}</div>
```

I wrote a challenge about this with working jsfiddle examples:
http://www.jomendez.com/2015/06/02/content-scope-challenge-5/